# JAVA Connect Server Socket to another Server Socket (e.g. client to client)?

Tags: java, p2p, serversocket

First of all sorry for the long winded title but i was unable to think of a suitable title, considering my question.

Now to the problem. I am creating a peer to peer chat application, which has the ability to send and receive files while also being able to chat to individual contacts.

I understand i can capture the ip of the client connecting to the server and store this, then when that user starts a chat session to another person. I can use that stored ip to create a connection between the two clients using the ServerSocket.

BUT i do not wish to pass one users ip to another users computer for security reasons so, what i am asking basically is there a way to connect two clients together without passing each client each others ip.

so for e.g

```
(all sockets have read / write buffers )

Client 1-- logs in --> Server ( a session ID 1 is created between the client 1 and server )
Client 2-- logs in --> Server ( a session ID 2 is created between the client 2 and server )

Client 1 --- Starts chat with client 2 ---> Server ( server connects session 1 and session 2)

Client 1 can then chat and send files to client two without passing it the ip.
```

I am sorry if this is a unclear question or even stupid but i could not think of a way to even Google this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to run the connection through a server. You could use the server to buffer the connection between the two clients and connect their communications in a way that would seem nearly seamless.

For example you could create a thread that, as long as both clients are connected, waits for input from client 1 and immediately pipes it to client 2. And the same would be necessary vice-versa. Is this the kind of solution you were looking for?

Comment: I will take this route if its the only way to achieve the goal, but say if a user sends a file will the file be sent via my server and hence use the servers bandwidth? I would prefer if it went client to client instead, but as i said am happy to do it this way if this is the only option. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BeatBox If you want the clients to be able to send information to each other without giving each other their IP addresses, you will either have to use your server or someone else's. I don't know how else the computers would be able to communicate.